# How to create json object in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had got a task to do jtable in ruby on rils.This is my controller

```
 def list
    @students = Student.all
    @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Records' => @students.map(&:attributes)}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @jtable}
    end
  end
def newstudent
    @student = Student.new
    @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Record' => @students.last(&:attributes)}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @jtable }
    end
  end
```

This is my index.html.erb file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <%=stylesheet_link_tag "jtable_blue","http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css",:media => "all" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.8.3.min","http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js","jquery.jtable.min"%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/students/list',
                createAction: '/students/new',
                updateAction: '/student/Update',
                deleteAction: '/student/Delete'
            },
            fields: {
                id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                name: {
                    title: 'name',
                    width: '40%'
                },
                sex: {
                    title: 'sex',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                branch: {
                    title: 'branch',
                    width: '30%'
                }

            }
        });

       jQuery('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="StudentTableContainer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I had got an error like "An error occured while communicating to the server." while adding a new user. How can i add new student?

Comment: can you explain more what's the question?

Comment: i edited my question. Hope you can understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller for this new student is  def newstudent

```
    @student = Student.new(params.reject {|key,value| key =="controller" || key =="action"})

    if @student.save 
      @jtable = {'Result' => 'OK','Record' => @student.attributes}
    else
     @jtable = {'Result' => 'ERROR','Message'=>'Empty'}
    end  
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @jtable }
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the record then you will have to add `:remote => true` in your form and your controller have something like this in your action:

```
if @user.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # do whatever
  end
end
```

If I'm reading your question correctly and you want to return just the last user you created in then in the `do whatever` part in my code snippet above you can add:

```
{'Result' => 'OK','Records' => @students.last(&:attributes)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used this code but by adding time i got an error, it shows like "An error occured while communicating to the server."

Comment: sir, i had got the solution for it.

Comment: Excellent, be sure to accept this and some of your previous question answers to make sure you get helped in future by the community.